# Xpath using getting no output

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, power-automate

I have an API output of an xml i am trying to parse
bellow is an example.

I am using Power Automate and trying to use xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<requests>
 <request id="31998">
  <employee id="6505">Peter Parker</employee>
  <start>2025-07-11</start>
  <end>2025-07-13</end>
  <created>2025-07-16</created>
  <status lastChanged="2024-01-16" lastChangedByUserId="91210">approved</status>
  <type id="84" icon="time-off-calendar">Vacation</type>
  <amount unit="days">2</amount>
  <dates>
   <date ymd="2024-03-11" amount="1"/>
   <date ymd="2024-03-12" amount="1"/>

  </dates>
  <notes>
   <note from="employee">Work Sucks and i dont wont to be here</note>
  </notes>
 </request>
```

my Xpath looks like this

`xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')), '(//request/@id)')`

my output is this

```
[
  "id=\"31998\"",
  "id=\"32214\"",
  "id=\"32339\""
]
```

i only want the numbers here so i tried the bellow

`xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')), 'string(//request/@id)')`

this only returns

`31998`

this is no good to me i want all the results. like the first instance.

so i tried this syntax

`xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')), 'string(//request/@id/text()')`
and
`xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')), 'string(//request/@id[text()]')`

both of these produce a null

i am now at loss and have loss all my patience
can you lovely peeps help

Comment: Thanks for all the help, i have decided to get the API to output JSON. i tried XML as i thought that would be easier to quantify. Apparently i was very wrong

Answer (score 0):

Good one, I can't make it work either.  Worst case, you may have to do some string manipulation.

Alternatively, you could use the **Advanced Data Operations** connector and the `XmlToJson` operation ...

[image: XmlToJson]

**Result**

[image: Result]

... and another alternative is to convert the XML to JSON and process it using a `Select` operation ...

[image: Select]

**Expressions**

From = `json(xml(variables('XML')))['requests']['request']`

Map Item = `item()[string('@id')]`

**Result**

[image]

Both approaches change the output somewhat but bottom line, you still get an array of values, they're just of type object, not of a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using XPath 1.0, which allows you to return a set of nodes, or a single string, but not a set of strings; it also doesn't have the string-join function which allows you to combine the string-values of a set of nodes by concatenation.

XPath 2.0+ processors have been available for many years, you don't have to live with these restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

Use Powershell with Xml Linq to parse data into a table and then export to CSV

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($request in $doc.Descendants('request'))
{
   $requestId = $request.Attribute('id').Value
   $employee = $request.Element('employee')
   $employeeId = $employee.Attribute('id').Value
   $employeeName = $employee.Value

   $newRow = [psCustomObject]@{
      RequestId = $requestId
      EmployeeId = $employeeId
      EmployeeName = $employeeName
   }

   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}

$table | Export-CSV -path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Request will look like this

```
"RequestId","EmployeeId","EmployeeName"
"31998","6505","Peter Parker"
```